# Assigning a variable to a dataset which is in a text file in python

Tags: python, matlab, variables, text, import-from-excel

I want to assign a variable to a dataset in `Python`. The data set is in a text file from `MS Excel`.

I used this following code in `matlab`:

```
 load data.txt
 a = data;
```

I want to replicate this in `Python`.

The trouble I have is using the right syntax to locate the file and how to actually write the same code in `Python`.

```
file location is C:\Users\user1\Documents\python\data.txt
```

Thanks

Comment: To answer your question one must know how excel writes data to text files, know the matlab load function and how it behaves for text files and know python. I suggest to rephrase your question, put in an example text file and what kind of output you expect, then probably every python programmer can answer it.

Answer (score 1):

You can always use `open()` function to open a specified file in python but you will need to modulate the path a little bit, you have 2 options either use `\\` in place of `\` to skip the escape characters or you can simply use `raw text` format as `r'C:\Users\user1\Documents\python\data.txt'`

```
open_file = open("C:\\Users\\user1\\Documents\\python\\data.txt")
contents = open_file.readlines()
print contents
```

Comment: As a follow up question, I am also using this matlab code to assign a variable to the different columns of the said data.
a = data;
b = a(:,1);
c = a(:,2);

How to do this in python also?

Thanks!